# Access all templates on classpath in spring

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

i am trying to get all templates i have saved in template folder in spring resources/templates . below is what i am trying , i am trying to access using /getTeamplateList , but it is not giving anything

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/getTemplateList", produces = "application/json")
public List getTemplates() throws IOException {

    List s = new ArrayList();
   File[] resourceFolderFiles = getResourceFolderFiles("classpath:/templates/");
    s.addAll(Arrays.asList(resourceFolderFiles));
    return s;
}

private static File[] getResourceFolderFiles (String folder) {
    ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    URL url = loader.getResource(folder);
    String path = url.getPath();
    return new File(path).listFiles();
}
```

Comment: how about `/templates/`. Buy anyway, it won't work as resources are not `File`s

Comment: remove hear /  like:  classpath:templates/ and recheck

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way:

```
@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

final List<String> result = Arrays.stream(loadResources()).map(resource -> resource.getFilename()).collect(Collectors.toList());


private Resource[] loadResources() throws IOException {
    return ResourcePatternUtils.getResourcePatternResolver(resourceLoader).getResources("classpath:/templates/*.html");
}
```

This will print

```
[
  "template1.html",
  "template2.html"
...
]
```

in the response.